# Changing the style of a button to a different style through a mouseover in WPF

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

I have just started using WPF and I am trying to design an application for logging hours for my volunteering group. Anyhow I am trying to make my buttons look like the calculator for Windows 7 buttons since that application is also designed in WPF and it would also impress the whole group.

I have gotten them to look like the buttons from Calculator (I have styles that look like the function and the digit buttons) but I can't get them to behave in the same way (a picture of the normal, the MouseOver and the click are attached at the end). I have my .xaml structured in the following way, I have `baseStyleButton` and `baseStyleButtonMouseOver` (I need help with defining this style too) defined in app.xaml and then I want to design `styleButtonUniversal` that "encapsulates" the two base styles and switches between them when the `MouseOver` event occurs. Similarly, I want to be able to extend this style to have a `click` event style too.

How do I achieve this in WPF or is there some other way that I can design my buttons that they both look cool and they are easy for a WPF beginner?

Also if anyone has any tips on how to achieve the MouseOver look of the calculator button, that would also be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for removing the link and posting the picture. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your already using a control template?

You can apply style triggers as follows

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource baseStyleButtonMouseOver}" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I actually am not using a control template since I have just started learning WPF and haven't gotten to the section on that in the book. I'm guessing that this is pretty much the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge, this is the most straightforward solution. (With or without control templates)